How did Putin's private car get into North Korea?
Putin gets lavish welcome in North Korea with vows of support

Kim greeted Putin, shaking hands, embracing and talking beside the Russian leader's plane. The pair then rode in Putin's Russian-made Aurus limousine to the Kumsusan State Guest House.

The same article has a photo of Putin and Kim before what looks like an ordinary plane, so presumably the car did not fly with him. But if the car didn't fly with him, how did it get into North Korea? Did someone drive it? If so, wouldn't the car have to leave several days before the trip?
Another possibility is that the car is not actually Putin's car, but Nikkei Asia also calls the car "Putin's car".

This is only a guess and I am not 100% sure about this, but I think there is a slight possibility that the Russian government may own two planes.

Since there's a rail link between two countries but not road, my guess would be that they put it on autorack railcar and sent it by rail.

@JörgWMittag This isn't the place for your conspiracy theories! (/s)

The Russian Presidential State Car has its own Wikipedia page. It says "On state visits, the state car is airlifted to the destination by an Ilyushin Il-76 transport aircraft." But there's no reference for that claim, and I can't find a good reference in a reliable source (although it's mentioned on some car websites).

I didn't vote to close this, but given your skepticism that it is Putin's car, this might have been more suitable to ask this on Skeptics.

Putin has multiple cars, the one he took to Pyongyang was apparently a gift for Kim.

Here are the two aircraft on the way to Pyongyang:

Presumably the car was on one of them.
(image capture from FlightRadar24)

The Il-II-96 doesn't seem to be a cargo plane though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-96 If the car was flown-in, it probably was on some other plane.

Russia and NK also have train connectivity for the movement of goods.

What @gottrolledtoomuchthisweek said. Also, the screenshoot shows 16 minutos of delay between the two flights. I would say that you want the car considerably earlier, considering that you may need to unload it (which could include opening cargo ramps, unfastening, checking that it did arrive correctly) and send it to the destination area through unfamiliar terrain. I guess the flight other than Putin's was probably carrying entourage, part of the security detail (some would have arrived earlier) and Russian journalists.

Indeed. Possibly another aircraft, or train. But some Il-96s have been converted to 'cargo'.

The Il-96-300PU is  not cargo though, assuming your image is correct (down to exact subtype). The cargo version is the Il-96-400T.

BTW, the Russia gov't doesn't seem to have any Il-96-400T. They're all owned by some other companies. There's a Il-96-400TZ owned by the MoD, but it's a tanker. The info on English wikipedia is from 2023.
